# install latest gearman on windows

Tags: php, php-extension, gearman

i know it is a repeated question but did not find answer to my problem. I am trying to install gearman on windows using [this link](http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/). I am stuck where it asks to ./configure gearman. In the latest versions of gearman, there is no configure file so this tutorial is not of use anymore. Solution i got after quite some research that i need to run **phpize** to create its configure file. And now i can not run phpize command on my system. it says command not found. Please help me if i can get this extension dll file or any other way i can run this.

Thanks

Comment: The configure in the example is for the actual gearman daemon, while you're talking about `phpize` and the extension dll. Are you trying to build the actual PHP extension or Gearman itself? If the former, you're probably better off with NET_Gearman, as I'm not familiar with anyone offering php_gearman for downloading readily compiled.

Comment: i just want to install and use gearman for my project on windows. i followed the example in the link, downloaded cygwin and its packages, downloaded lib*, and when i tried to make gearman as stated it needed configure file. so i need to get phpize working to get this file. Please guide if there is anyother way

Comment: You cannot use phpize to generate a configure file for gearmand itself. phpize is used for generating a `configure` file for the PHP extension, which assumes that libgearman is already available.